# Remove event after adding it directly to fullCalender

Tags: jquery, events, fullcalendar

I want to remove event after adding it directly to [full calender](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/), when drop the event I add the id to the event object and when click on the event I want to remove the event. I make alert for the id and it alerts correctly but the event doesn't removed event the ajax code is executed and the event is deleted from server side.

**The same code works correctly when adding the event and refresh the page then remove the event.**

```
 eventClick: function(event, element) {

            var current = $(this);

            if(confirm('Are you sure from removing the event?')){
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: url+"delCalEvent",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    data:{
                        'eventId':event.id
                    },
                    success:function(result){
                        if(result  == "1"){

                       //what should I do here to remove the event without refreshing the page
                      $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event.id); 


                        }

                    },
                    error: function (request, status, error) {  
                        alert('Error on deleting the event ');
                        revertFunc();
                    }
                });


            } 

        }
```

Comment: Do you tried to rerender the calendar: $('#calendar').fullCalendar("rerenderEvents");?

Comment: `removeEvents` should work as you have it, without need to `rerenderEvents`... are you sure you are getting `result==1` from server?

Comment: @axel.michel, yes I tried to "rerenderEvents" and "renderEvents" events but no response

Comment: @MaxD, yes I am sure it returns 1 from the server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work.. But maybe fullcalendar is not getting the right reference.. Try to use one of the methods below to get the object reference:

```
// get specif event (reference)
var specificEvent = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents', event.id);
```

or

```
// get last event added (reference)
var clientEvents = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');
var lastEvent = clientEvents[clientEvents.length-1];
```

then try to use one of the following methods to remove it:

```
lastEvent.id = '';
lastEvent.start = '';
lastEvent.end = '';
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', lastEvent);
```

or

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', lastEvent);
```

Comment: It works properly with creating empty event and "updateEvent", but please remove <code>this </code> because it cause an error.

Comment: yes, I have wrongly copied the word 'this'..already removed it, tnks